# How to access the second div node in Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The following HTML code is as proceeds:

```
<div class="lower-text"> 
<div data-text="winScreen.yourCodeIs">Your Code Is:</div> 
<div>GENERATEDCODE</div>
```

What I'm trying to access is the second div node (the randomly generated number) in the class "lower-text"

```
 try:
    element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'lower-text'))
    )
finally:
    found = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='lower-text'][2]").text
    print(found)
```

This is what I've tried with no success.
I am unsure as how to access the second div node. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below solution ::

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@data-text='winScreen.yournumberis']/following-sibling::div")))
    print element.text
```

Also you need to add below imports

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as Wait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not being clear enough. I am not looking for winScreen.yourNumberis. I am looking for the randomly generated number to appear. Appreciate the help though.

Comment: please check updated solution , Kindly accept answer and also hit upvote button once yor issue is resolved –

Comment: Unfortunately getting a timeout exception.

This is the html code in better format.

`div class="lower-text">
<div data-text="winScreen.yourCodeIs">Your Code Is:</div><div>GENERATEDCODE</div>`

Once again, I am trying to access the GENERATEDCODE node.

Comment: Increase your delay to WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

Comment: Got it. However it is now saying to text attributed to it. "Nonetype" has no attribute "text."

Comment: How manyy elements you are getting with above xpath if you are getting list of elements then change it to //*[@data-text='winScreen.yournumberis']/following-sibling::div[1] and try again

Comment: check if its present on a iframe ?

Comment: similar question asked again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60878849/printing-text-from-2nd-div-in-class-in-python-selenium/60880144#60880144