# Printing Text from 2nd Div in Class in Python + Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

newbie here trying to learn Selenium. I have the following HTML Code:

```
<div class="lower-text">
<div data-text="winScreen.yourCodeIs">Your Code Is:</div>
<div>OUTPUTCODE</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to only print the text OUTPUTCODE, however the following code only prints "Your Code Is:".

`text = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('lower-text')
 for test in text:
     print(test.text)`

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below xpath.

```
//div[@class='lower-text']/div[last()]
```

You code should be

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='lower-text']/div[last()]").text)
```

Comment: This unfortunately prints a blank line.

Comment: check if the div is wrapped in an iframe. If that's case then you have to switch to the frame using `driver.switch_to.frame` and then run the line from my answer.

Comment: If you want help in checking if the element is wrapped in iframe just try `//div[@class='lower-text']/div[last()]/ancestor::html` [xpath in dev tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870609/is-there-a-way-to-learn-xpath-without-using-firebug-or-xpath-as-firefox-is-not-s/55870909#55870909)

Answer (score 0):

Try below Solutions:

**1. Xpath :**

```
//div[@class='gs_copied']
```

**2. CSS selector**

```
.lower-text > div:nth-child(2)
```

Your site is unstable and not always generating coupon code.Currently I am getting below error(check screenshot). So wont able to identify elements which i have mentioned above.

You need to amend your logic based on functionality and if person is Unlucky for getting coupon code then you have to write script to handle other functionality based on your site, (e.g: Check out our Hot Deals Page)

[image]

Comment: Tried both, both print nothing unfortunately. For reference, OUTPUTCODE is a string of numbers and letters with no spaces.

Comment: Try this : //div[contains(text(),'Your Code Is:')]/following-sibling::div[1]

Comment: yes check if its present on iframe then switch to iframe using driver.switch_to.frame(0).  if not then would be great if you provide url of your site

Comment: .lower-text > div:nth-child(2) this will resolve your issue

Comment: I have updated solution please refer latest answers

Comment: For XPath, it is unable to locate the element.
For CSS selector, I am getting 'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'text'

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach:

```
text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Your Code Is:']//following-sibling::div[text()]").get_attribute('innerHTML')
print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have copy pasted your html part in a new text file and tried the following xpath which work perfectly:

//div[@class='lower-text']/div[text()='Your Code Is:']/following-sibling::div

Attaching screenshot link also. Please have a look and hopefully it will solve your problem.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLLvl.jpg